aws ec2 amazon linux yum repository loaded manually
How to manage linux repositories on amazon linux?
list installed packages
yum list installed
in case of yum update is not found
How to manage manually on amazon linux?
what linux distribution applies on amazon linux ?
manually upload amazon linux repository to load a package and be recognized by sudo yum update to list the package installed on sudo yum list installed

You can use the following cmd to add repos to the Amazon Linux,
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://www.example.com/repository.repo

Additionally you can enable the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) using the following CMD,
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel

You can also use the following to install the packages directly like this,
sudo yum install links
or
sudo yum install package.rpm

Also, the Amazon Linux is based on RedHat Enterprise Linux(RHEL) so if you find that the package you're trying to install is not in AL's repo, you can Google and add the repo url using --add-repo option
